# Kentico 8.2 image to base64

Tags: c#, image, base64, kentico, vcf-vcard

I am trying to convert an image to base64 in order to display it in a vCard (ver 4).  I have tried using:

```
MediaFileInfo imageFile = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileInfo(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, filePath, null);
```

However `imageFile.FileBinary` is null (everything else e.g. `FileSize`, `ID`, `GUID` etc. are correct).  Any idea why this is the case?

I've also tried using a `FileStream`:

```
FileStream file = FileStream.New(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Image imageFile = Image.FromStream(file.SystemStream);
```

The problem I'm running into here is that it seems to expect `filePath` to be an absolute path.  I have to use a relative path.

Is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you storing images in your database? If not, then the binary will always be empty. As for the FileStream method, it will have to be an absolute path to the disk because that is how System.IO works. There are a number of ways you can get the absolute path (Server.MapPath, etc.) that may help you get the values you need.

Comment: Thank you.  Images are not being stored in the db for this project, so it looks like I'll have to go with FileStream/System.IO.